# php, regex, xml

Tags: php, xml, regex

I have some sort of ... xml document as below :

```
<file src="136090000-136100000">
  <member id="136090000">
        <Name>
              <![CDATA[DOSEKUN DANIEL ADETUNJI]]>
              </Name>
        <Email>
              <![CDATA[dosekun2d200@yahoo.com]]>
              </Email>
        <DateRegistration>
              <![CDATA[10/19/2010 8:46:57 PM]]>
              </DateRegistration>
  </Member>
  <usafisMember id="136090001">
        <Name>
              <![CDATA[yoleida colina]]>
              </Name>
        <Email>
              <![CDATA[yole_g1972@hotmail.com]]>
              </Email>
        <DateRegistration>
              <![CDATA[10/19/2010 8:47:08 PM]]>
              </DateRegistration>
  </usafisMember>
  <usafisMember id="136090002">
        <Name>
              <![CDATA[Homero Valdovinos]]>
              </Name>
        <Email>
              <![CDATA[felicida2d_9091@hotmail.com]]>
              </Email>
        <DateRegistration>
              <![CDATA[10/19/2010 8:47:01 PM]]>
              </DateRegistration>
  </Member>
```

I need to extract the member id , name, email and DateRegistration but as you can see the xml is not very well formatted . I tried with simple xml which obviously doesn't work but nether regex doesn't seem to work . Here is the pattern that I tried :

```
$pattern = "/<Name><\\!\\[CDATA\\[(.*)\\]\\]><\/Name>/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $xml_content, $matches);
$name = $matches[1][0][v];
echo " name is $name ";
```

Comment: Use an XML parser, like SimpleXML.

Comment: Sorry for being obvious, but why don't you use http://ru2.php.net/simplexml?

Comment: Is the XML always missing the closing file tag or could there be any other invalid constructs?

Comment: I have tried "$xml_content = file_get_contents("/var/www/html/xml/$file_name");

//print_r($xml_content);
  $xml = simplexml_load_file("$xml_content");

echo $xml->getName() . "<br />";
" and here is the log file http://pastebin.com/674yGpsE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $x='<file src="136090000-136100000">
      <usafisMember id="136090000">
            <Name>
                  <![CDATA[DOSEKUN DANIEL ADETUNJI]]>
                  </Name>
            <Email>
                  <![CDATA[dosekun2d200@yahoo.com]]>
                  </Email>
            <DateRegistration>
                  <![CDATA[10/19/2010 8:46:57 PM]]>
                  </DateRegistration>
      </usafisMember>
      <usafisMember id="136090001">
            <Name>
                  <![CDATA[yoleida colina]]>
                  </Name>
            <Email>
                  <![CDATA[yole_g1972@hotmail.com]]>
                  </Email>
            <DateRegistration>
                  <![CDATA[10/19/2010 8:47:08 PM]]>
                  </DateRegistration>
      </usafisMember>
      <usafisMember id="136090002">
            <Name>
                  <![CDATA[Homero Valdovinos]]>
                  </Name>
            <Email>
                  <![CDATA[felicida2d_9091@hotmail.com]]>
                  </Email>
            <DateRegistration>
                  <![CDATA[10/19/2010 8:47:01 PM]]>
                  </DateRegistration>
      </usafisMember>
        </file>
    ';

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($x);



foreach ($xml->usafisMember as $usafisMember){
echo 'Name: '. $usafisMember->Name.'<br>';
}
```

had to add close file but other wise worked as expected

Answer (score 3):

Parsing XML with regex is [almost certainly wrong](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html). Use a dedicated XML parser. There are plenty available for php.

Comment: XML cannot be either well-formatted or not well-formatted; it can only be valid. If it's not valid XML then you ought to find XML that is, otherwise you are never going to be able to do this reliably.

Comment: (Your XML looks ok to me at first glance, apart from the missing closing tag.)